# Making a sequence alternating

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I have the sequence $\{x_{j}=k+\frac{1+2(j-\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^{n-i})}{2^{n-k}}\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$, where $n= \lfloor log_{2}j \rfloor$ and k$=\{l\in \mathbb{N}:$maximum l s.t. $\sum_{i=0}^{l}2^{n-i}\leq j\}$, and I want to get the sequence :

$y_{j}= x_{\frac{j+1}{2}}$  if j odd and $y_{j}=-x_{\frac{j}{2} }$  if j even

into a single formula eg. $y_{j}=(-1)^{j+1}x_{f(j)}$.

What would be a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ceiling function:
$$f(j) = \left\lceil\frac{j}{2} \right\rceil$$

(With your use of $f(j)$.)